# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing on MRJob

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am working with MRJob through python and when I try to create a class, I get a synthax error. It's highlighting the colon. What am I missing? Here is my code:

```
class Bacon_count(MRJob):
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are defining an empty class, but in an unproper way. In Python an empty class should contain a `pass` statement, in your case:

```
class Bacon_count(MRJob):
   pass
```

Also, take into account how to define single class methods in multiple cells, if that's what you are trying to do, as it is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45161393/jupyter-split-classes-in-multiple-cells/45161859).